# How to get records based on info in Rails belongs_to record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I have 2 models TourHdr and TourDetail.  TourDetail belongs_to tour_hdr and TourHdr has_many tour_details.  TourHdr also has an attribute called status.

I want to define a method in TourDetail which will give me all TourDetails where the status field in the associated TourHdr record = Live.

I tried the following:

```
def self.status(status)
  where(:tour_hdr.status == status)
end
```

status here can be 'Live' or 'Cancelled'.

Rails complains that there is no tour_hdr method for Class TourDetail.  What is the correct syntax here?

In the console if I do:

```
td = TourDetail.first
puts td.tour_hdr.status
```

It works fine.  I'm guessing it's because td is an 'Instance' of TourDetail rather than the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
joins(:tour_hdr).where(:tour_hdrs => {:status => status})
```

Comment: Thanks Mik that worked but you have a typo that I can't edit.  The where clause tour_hdr should be plural i.e. :tour_hdrs.  Then it works. I also have a confession to make.  tour_hdr only holds the status_id and I actually want to get to a table called tour_statuses which has the attribute of statusdesc where 'Live' really resides.  Please can you update your description to show how I might get to tour_statuses.statusdesc.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can set all associations as `joins(:tour_hdr => :tour_status).where(:tour_statuses => {:statusdesc => status})`

Comment: Thanks VERY MUCH for that.  It works great.  Where in the documentation can I find this?